# MYSQL: copy a column but change type

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, copy, multiple-columns

My need is really simple.

I have a big table, this table has a column named A. Its type is int and the only values A can hold at the moment are 1, 2 or 3.

I want to alter my table, create a new column named B, and copy A into it but have B with type string/varchar.

I already checked MYSQL and I see it handles converting int into string really easily.

e.g. before

```
index| A |
  0  | 1 |
  1  | 1 |
  2  | 3 |
```

will turn into

```
index| A | B |
  0  | 1 |'1'|
  1  | 1 |'1'|
  2  | 3 |'3'|
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Strawberry No, I just wanted your attention.

Comment: I wonder if you want to include quotes in your new column

Comment: @P.Salmon no, just wanted to emphasize these are strings.

Comment: `I already checked MYSQL and I see it handles converting int into string really easily.` so what's the problem?

Comment: A one off lump of code might be sufficient but out of interest how do you intend to manage this new field - do you intend to populate both fields on every insert and update, do you want to automatically populate b from the a, would you be happy to periodically maintain b?

Comment: @P.Salmon A supported one thing. I want it to support two things now. once B works fine and I see I took care of all of A usages and moved them into B, I will delete A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column, then copy into it:

```
alter table mytable add column B varchar(10);
update mytable set B = A;
```

Implicit casting will apply.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ab267a80e2b816b791164c1338fe541)**

Answer (score 1):

You've basically described in your question exactly what you have to do:

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD COLUMN B VARCHAR(10) -- adjust size as required
;
UPDATE test
SET B = A
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3DkEGpzNsaD8ok2fN8owR8/0)